# Make Command-line mode type <Esc> and Ctrl commands

Tags: command-line

Imagine you want to quote the word below. If `|` is the cursor position you can easily quote the word with `cw""<Esc>P` from Normal mode.

```
|below
```

I want to achieve the same behaviour in Command-line mode. My question is how can I say to the Command-line mode that I want to type an `<Esc>`. I tried `:norm cw""<Esc>P` and some other variations but I just get `""<Esc>P` instead of `"below"`.

Still related to this I would like to know how can I make Command-line mode type Ctrl commands. For example I could quote the aforementioned word with `cw"<C-r>""<Esc>` instead. But then I would need Command-line to type `<C-r>` for me. How can I do this?

Comment: Just like there is `<C-x><C-e>` in readline to edit the command-line in `$EDITOR`, you have `<C-f>` in Vim to open the command-line window. See `:help cmdline-window`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<C-v>` is what you are looking for. It allows you to enter literal characters (e.g., a literal `Esc` instead of the string "Esc") without requiring you to escape anything.

```
:norm cw""<C-v><Esc>P
```

displays as:

```
:norm cw""^[P
```

and will do what you want (i.e., quote the word). You can also use this with other `<C-?>` mappings. For example, your second request:

```
:norm cw"<C-v><C-r>""
```

displays as:

```
:norm cw"^R""
```

And will result in the same as the above. There's no need to include the extra `Esc` at the end.

Answer (score 11):

This is because special keys like `<Esc>` are not translated in `normal` commands, and are treated like you pressed <kbd><</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>></kbd>.  To remedy this, you can use an `exec` command.  Like so:

```
:exec "norm cw\"\"\<Esc>P"
```

Note that you must put a backslash before the quotes and the `<Esc>`, and using single quotes instead of double quotes will not work.

Comment: Does this work for Ctrl commands too? How should I write them in the command?

Comment: Yes, it should work.  You can write them like so: `"\<C-{insert key}>"`

Comment: Thanks for that last remark! I almost got there myself, and this was the final missing piece. `:exe "normal \<C-A>"`, very useful in a script.

Answer (score 2):

Command-line mode is different; you cannot use the same (normal mode) editing commands there. You can find a list of commands at `:help c_CTRL-V`.

Now, there's the *command-line window* (`:help command-line-window`), which can be entered via `q:` from normal- and `<C-F>` from command-line mode. In *that* window, you can use all normal commands and mappings, so that would be option 1.

Option 2 is special mappings for command-line mode. As I said, you cannot use the approach via `:normal` et al. Key to defining those is the `:help c_CTRL-\_e` mapping, which "evaluate[s] {expr} and replace[s] the whole command line with the result." Here's a simple example that only works correctly at the end of the command-line:

```
:cnoremap <F1> <C-\>esubstitute(getcmdline(), '\w\+$', '"&"', '')<CR>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP meant to create mapping for the command line, but to execute a mapping from the command line.